# how to add new row after button was clicked, html jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

https://jsfiddle.net/kd4hce2o/

I have a table that has a column for adding a comment, how do i add a new row after the button was clicked?

That button is dynamically added after a new row is inserted, here is my code:

```
<table id="items" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"/></th>
    <th width="2%">AC</th>
    <th width="15%">Codigo</th>
    <th width="38%">Articulo</th>
    <th width="15%">Precio</th>
    <th width="15%">Cantidad</th>
    <th width="15%">Total</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="row_1">
    <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-success addrow" type="button">AC</button></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="items[code][]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="items[name][]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="items[price][]" readonly="readonly" id="price_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="items[quantity][]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="items[total][]" readonly="readonly" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and here is my script:

```
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
html = '<tr>';
html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
html += '<td><button class="btn btn-success addrow" type="button" id="addrow_'+i+'">AC</button></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="items[code][]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="items[name][]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text"  name="items[price][]" readonly="readonly" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text"  name="items[quantity][]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '<td><input type="text"  name="items[total][]" readonly="readonly" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
html += '</tr>';
$('#items').append(html);
i++;
});


$(document).on("click", '.addrow', function (){
newrow = '<tr><td colspan="7"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td></tr>';
$('#items').append(newrow);
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle looks like working fine. Whats wrong in your code?

Comment: The problem is for example, if you add 3 rows and then click the first or second "AC" button, the comment input will appear at the end of the table, not exactly below where the button was clicked. @xyz

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just clone() your first row rather than manually building up the html for a second row?

Comment: @KrisOye I need the IDs to auto-increment, can I do that with the clone method?

Comment: @raysn0w, i see. so, you want the input to be appended right after the row(AC) that was clicked. is that correct?

Comment: @xyz exactly! is driving me crazy, my brain is melted for today.

Comment: @raysn0w, check my answer.

Comment: @xyz I dont understand why Im not supposed to comment just to say thank you, BUT THANK YOU!

Comment: @raysn0w, you are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/). [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kd4hce2o/1/).

```
$(document).on("click", '.addrow', function (){
    newrow = '<tr><td colspan="7"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td></tr>';
    $(this).parent().parent().after(newrow);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The row you are adding is broken.  Also, make sure you are loading jQuery with a quick `$` in console to see it is defined.  If you change the above `$(".addmore").on('click',function(){` to `$(document).on('click', '.addrow', function(){` and get rid of the one it's using down below then you have new, good-looking rows, and each row's event listener works.

Small stuff: `var html = '<tr>';` and `var newrow = ...`.  They are local vars.

Comment: Check my previous previous comment, everything is working, the problem is the position of the AC input. you can check it on jsfiddle.